# Why am I getting a wrong output for this code (to print the number of palindromes in an array)?

Tags: c

> find the number of palindromes in an array

What I did was to first find out the number of digits of the number and then multiply the first remainder with the digit-1-th term and then remainder two with digit-2-th term and so on. if `sum == num` then it adds 1 to run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int a[30], i, n, cont = 0, j, rem, run = 0, sum = 0, b[300], c[300];

    printf("Enter the number of elements\n");

    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Enter the array elements\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        c[i] = a[i];
        b[i] = a[i];
        cont = 0;

        while (b[i] != 0) {
            b[i] = b[i] / 10;
            cont++;
        }
        sum = 0;

        while (a[i] != 0) {
            rem = a[i] % 10;
            sum = sum + rem * pow(10, cont - 1);
            cont--;
            a[i] = a[i] / 10;
        }
        if (sum == c[i])    
            run++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", run);
}
```

is there any problem with the `for` and `while` loops?

Comment: Apologies, I misread. Your question would benefit with formatted code.

Comment: You are mixing integers with real numbers `sum=sum+rem*pow(10,cont-1);`. Provide your own implementation of `power` function which takes integer and returns integer. And check results.

Comment: As a fun learning exercise, try doing this with `float`s

Comment: OT: regarding this kind of statement: `scanf("%d", &n);`  when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%d", &n);`  This allows the user to input negative numbers (<0) Suggest declaring 'n' as 'unsigned' and using the '%u' input format specifier

Comment: the posted code will  (or not) increment `run` depending on if the values entered by the user are exactly expressible as `double` values.  It that what your trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your programs works but several remarks can be done

- check the result of *scanf*
- check the range of *n*
- you do not need arrays *b* and *c* and even you use them as array their size can be 30 as *a*

A proposal :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

#define N 30

int main()
{
  int a[N],i,n,run=0;

  printf("Enter the number of elements\n");
  if ((scanf("%d",&n) != 1) || (n < 1) || (n > N)) {
    puts("invalid number of element");
    return -1;
  }

  printf("Enter the array elements\n");

  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    if (scanf("%d",&a[i]) != 1)
    {
      puts("invalid number");
      i -= 1;
      continue;
    }
  }

  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    int b  = a[i];
    int cont=0;

    while(b!=0)
    {
      b=b/10;
      cont++;
    }

    int sum=0;

    b = a[i];
    while(b!=0)
    {
      int rem=b%10;

      sum=sum+rem*pow(10,cont-1);
      cont--;
      b /= 10;
    }

    if(sum==a[i]) {
      printf("%d is a palindrome\n", a[i]);
      run++;
    }
  }

  printf("%d\n",run);
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wextra p.c -lm
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter the number of elements
3
Enter the array elements
1
12
12321
1 is a palindrome
12321 is a palindrome
2
```

Note you can also read the numbers a string to be more general and avoid calculus